# store @ManytoOne relationship in elastiicsearch in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using JpaRepository and ElasticsearchRepository(spring-data-3.x) in spring boot Application ,saving data in relational db as well as in elasticsearch.

**Below is Student Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Document(indexName = "student" ,type="_doc")
class Student{

@id
private Long id;
private String studentName;
----
}
```

**Below is course entity**

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "course")
  @Document(indexName = "course" ,type="_doc")
  class Course{
   
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String courseName;
   ------
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "courses", allowSetters = true)
  private Student student;

}
```

When I saved data in db using repository ,`id` of student is stored in `course` relation and when we fetch data ,course data fetched with student. But when I store data in elasticsearch `student` data stored as a sub-document in `course` document. If I make any updation in student like change student name and then search course for that student from elastic search .It shows old data  as on updation sub-document is not updated. So How we can store data in elasticsearch when we are using relationship @ManyToOne.

Comment: Elasticsearch is not a relational database system. If you want to change a student property, you need to update the embedded student of the  course documents that contain this student. Or don't embed the student in the course entity but only it's id. But you will have to do the matching of students into courses then by yourself.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch - I am looking for `Parent-child implementation`  but did not find any example.

Comment: There is the join-type https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/parent-join.html but this is for a parent-child relationship between documents(entities) of the same type - not for joining together different document types.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch - `parent-child relationship between documents(entities) of the same type - not for joining together different document types` means ?

Comment: yes. Elasticsearch or other document based stores do not work like relational databases. You have to build the appropriate data model for them, you cannot just use the same ones you use for an RDBMS.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch  what will be the best approach in my case as my data changes frequently in Parent Entity.